# unexpectedly see object on other schemas

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I am working for a company that use Weblogic application and an Oracle 11g database.

We have many test machines to test the application. Each machines connect to the same instance of database but use different schemas.

For example, machine number 1 use schema `test1` and has its own set of tables such as `test1.payment`, `test1.customer` etc. And machine number 2 use schema `test2` and also has tables `test2.payment`, `test2.customer`, etc.

Usually, if we are accessing database on schema `test1` and apply the following query

`select * from all_objects where object_name = 'PAYMENT'`

we would get a row where object_name = 'PAYMENT' and owner = 'TEST1'

One day the application on test machine number 2 failed to start with error message `There is more than one owner for type FOO, in the database`, where `FOO` is a pseudonym.

I inspected the type `FOO` in the database with this SQL

`select * from all_objects where object_name = 'FOO'`

and get rows where owner are from every schemas, and thought it is the root cause.

I am not allowed to edit the part of the application's source code that causes the problem. So I would like to fix it in database site. But DBAs will be absent for a while and I don't have DBA privileges, but I can access all schemas `test1`, `test2`, ...

The question is:

**Why `select * from all_objects where object_name = 'FOO'` returns rows from other schemas and how to make it that it return only one row from the current schema?**

Answer (score 0):

ALL_OBJECTS shows all objects in the database that your login can 'see.' USER_OBJECTS would only show objects in your schema. DBA_OBJECTS shows all objects in the database, whether you can access them or not. That's why querying DBA_ views are often faster than querying ALL_ views, b/c there's no security check before populating the result set.

From the [DOCS](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/datadict.htm#CNCPT2140)

> > ALL_
>
> All users
>
> Objects to which user has privileges
>
> Includes objects owned by user. These views obey the current set of
>   enabled roles.

You can get rid of the GRANT on the other object or schema which allows the conflicting object to get resolved by the database on your query - but that would likely also require DBA intervention.

You can also change the application code to include the SCHEMA explicitly (TEST1 or TEST2) in your query so the other object isn't found.